# Partitioning Beaglebone internal mmc for 2 kernels

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

Does anyone have any experience with storing two separate Linux kernel images within the 4GB internal mmc memory of the Beaglebone (2 default Debian images or anything else)?

I am trying to implement an OTA update solution whereby of course I will need to have two kernels in memory, the one being updated and the working one. Must I use the SD card?

Answer (score 1):

You should have more then one partition for storing the kernel image in your partition layout. One example layout could be, considering only the kernel parts,using yocto's WIC feature

```
part kernel0 --fixed-size 20M --fstype=ext4 --label kernel0 --source bootimg-partition
part kernel1 --fixed-size 20M --fstype=ext4 --label kernel1
```

Based on you OTA functions, you can update the u-boot/bootloader environment variable using `fw_setenv` in linux to fetch the kernel accordingly.

Note: the above partition layout is only for kernel representation and you should also include rootfs and other partitions based on your need. This example is shown using [WIC](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.2/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#creating-partitioned-images-using-wic).

Answer (score 1):

We use a synchron a/b (dual) boot layout on 1GB NAND.
You can try [rauc](https://rauc.io) with at least 6 slots / partitions: kernel0, devicetree0, rootfs0, kernel1, devicetree1, rootfs1.

The kernel partition are often only 10MB big. Devicetree partitions even smaller.